# Finding greatest sum of elements of array which is divisible by a given number

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

It is from a programming question.

The question is as follows:

An array of numbers will be given along with the number k we have to divide with.
And we have to choose elements from that array such that the sum of those element is divisible by k. The sum of those elements should be as large as possible.

Input:

On the first line n, denoting the number of elements.

On the next line n numbers are given.

On the next line k is given by which we have to divide.

Output:

Largest sum as possible by choosing elements from that array s.t. sum is divisible by k.

Sample Input:

```
5 
1 6 2 9 5
8
```

Sample Output:

```
16
```

Note that 16 is obtainable by more than one combinations of numbers, but we're here concerned only about maximum sum.

**My Proposed Solution:**

I traverse over array and maintain cumulative sum in an array b for the given input array like:

```
b=[1 7 9 18 23]
```

and taking mod of numbers in array b by k and store it to

```
c=[1 7 1 2 7]
```

Now the numbers having the same value in c i.e. index 0 and index 2; index 1 and index 4.
Now i have got all solutions, and the answer would be

```
max(b[2]-b[0],b[4]-b[1])
```

And is in a case three indexes have same value in c i.e. in case where

```
c=[1 2 3 1 1 2]
```

The answer would be

```
max(b[4]-b[0],b[5]-b[1])
```

Basically subtracting the leftmost occurrence of that number with the rightmost occurrence.

**My solution only works if there are contiguos elements s.t. sum of elements is divisible by k. Expecting a description of the correct solution**

Comment: Are all the numbers integers ? All positive ?

Comment: @PaulR yes all are integers.

Comment: Are all the integers positive ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark reference for b[5] is not for the case , i have given, i just assumed an another case for clarification purpose. I gave c array for which i didn't provided a b array.

Comment: @PaulR yes,all integers are positive, and can be stored in 32 bits.

Comment: Do you have to choose contiguous elements from the array, or will any do? For example, if the array is `1 2 3 4 5`, can we choose `1 2 5`?

Comment: @IVlad oh, yes i got the mistake in my algo, it works for only consecutive. Actually in the problem we can choose any element irrespective of their position.

Comment: Your algorithm is clearly incorrect; consider the input `5, {6,2,1,5,9}, 8` (that is the same as your test case but with a permutation of the list of integers), your algorithm produces the answer `8`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe your solution is not correct, since you're only considering consecutive numbers. For example, if the input is

```
4
1 6 2 9
8
```

The answer would still be 16 (=1+6+9). I'm not sure whether your solution can give this answer.

---

For an efficient solution for this problem, try dynamic programming. I would omit the details but point out the essentials.

Suppose the numbers are in an array `a[i]` where `i` is from `1` to `n`.

Let `f(i,j)` denote the largest sum you can get by choosing numbers from `a[1]` through `a[i]` (i.e. `a[1], a[2], ..., a[i]`) and also the sum modulo `k` is `j`.

Consider `f(i,j)`, obviously we have two choices: (1) include `a[i]` in  the sum; (2) do not include `a[i]`. Thus `f(i,j) = max{ f(i-1,x) + a[i], f(i-1,j) }` where `x + a[i] == j (mod k)`. The boundary is `f(0,j) = 0` for all `j`

---

To implement this algorithm, the basic skeleton is as follows.

```
for (j = 0; j < k; j++) f[0][j] = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    x = (j + k - a[i]%k) % k;
    f[i][j] = max(f[i-1][x], f[i-1][j]);
  }
```

In order to save memory, you can also use an array of size `[2][k]` instead of `[n][k]`:

```
for (j = 0; j < k; j++) f[0][j] = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    x = (j + k - a[i]%k) % k;
    f[i%2][j] = max(f[(i-1)%2][x], f[(i-1)%2][j]);
  }
```

You can also use `i&1` (and `(i-1)&1`) to speed up modulo of `2`.

---

Further references on dynamic programming:

- A Tutorial on TopCoder: [Dynamic Programming: From novice to advanced](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/)
- *Dynamic Programming - A Computational Tool* by Prof. Art Lew and Dr. Holger Mauch
- *Dynamic Programming - Foundations and Principles* by Moshe Sniedovich

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I suppose my solution can be easier to understand for you as a beginner. In order to save memory so we don't end up with `O(n*k)`, you can use this `[2][k]` version safely without overwriting previously calculated results. However, in a classical knapsack problem, you can do this to the knapsack capacity because it's strictly decreasing in that sense.

Comment: thanks, i got the explanation. Could you please help me with some good reference to read more on dynamic programming.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I updated the answer with some references. You can try to go one by one if interested :-D

Comment: @XiaoJia, would be of great help if you could write recursive code for above dp.I want to drive from recursion to memoization to dp. That way I can understand much better. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a variant of [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem): you want the subset with the largest sum divisible by `k`.

Let `dp[i] = largest sum obtainable that gives remainder i modulo k`. However, in order to avoid using the same element twice, we must use two arrays because of the modulo: the array containing the current values of `dp` (`dp1`) and the array containing the previous values of `dp` (dp2). We have:

```
a = original array
dp1[*] = dp2[*] = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
  for j = k - 1 down to 0 do
    dp1[j] = max(dp1[j], dp2[(j - a[i]) mod k] + a[i])

  copy dp1 to dp2: on the next iteration, the current array will must become the
  previous one (*)
```

**(*)** Note that you do not necessarily have to do any copying if execution time is very important. You can use an array `dp[2, k]` and use its lines alternatively: computer from `dp[0, _]` to `dp[1, _]` in odd iterations, and the other way around in even iterations.

The answer will be in either of `dp1[0, 0]` or `dp2[0, 0]`. The memory used is `O(n + k)` and the time complexity `O(n * k)`.

**Note:** when implementing this, you might need to do the modulo this way in order to avoid negative values: `((j - a[i]) mod k + k) mod k`. Or you can use an `if` and only add `k` if the initial value is negative.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I suppose this would not be the answer because (i) `j` may be less than `a[i]`, and (ii) there's no guarantee that `(j - a[i]) mod k` is less than `j` (note it's modulo, not directly subtraction!). Don't mix this with the classical knapsack problem. :-)

Comment: thanks, actually i have studied dynamic programming already but usually couldn't figure it out in new problem. So i guess the problem is with my understanding of it, so if you know any good reference for dynamic programming, please provide it to me.

Comment: @XiaoJia - to both your points: so what? I don't see how that affects the correctness. It's precisely because we're working mod `k` that those things do not matter.

Comment: (i) need to trick the `mod` operator so it handles negative numbers; (ii) in that case wouldn't it overwrite the actually needed `dp[]` value?

Comment: @XiaoJia - (i) you don't really need to trick anything, just use the standard definition. In programming languages you might need to add `+k` if the initial result is < 0, I have added a note. (ii) No, by subtracting `a[i]` from `j` and then adding `a[i]` to the associated sum, we get a sum which is `j` modulo `k`.

Comment: (i) suppose it's `(-6)%3` so `+3` only once doesn't solve the issue, you also need to `a[i] mod k` (as shown in my code); (ii) still cannot understand your point. From my understanding, you're trying to save memory so that `dp[i][j]` and `dp[i-1][j]` can share the same place. In a classical knapsack problem, you can do this by looping downwards, because the `j` (a capacity in that sense) is subtracted by the weight of an item, so it's strictly decreasing. But in this problem, there's a modulo `k` there, so you may overwrite meaningful (previous calculated) `dp[]` values.

Comment: @XiaoJia - (i) -6 % 3 = 0. 0 is not < 0, so we do nothing. -7 mod 3 = -1. -1 + 3 = 2. You add after the initial modulo, not before. (ii) I still don't see how I'm overwriting anything I shouldn't. The only thing that may get overwritten is `dp[j]`, and `j` always descends.

Comment: @IVlad Shouldn't use the word overwrite, but your code may add `a[i]` twice (or more I suppose) to `dp[j]`. I'm trying to come up with a concrete example to show this.

Comment: @IVlad Suppose there's only 1 `a[1]=2` and `k=3`. Follow your code, `j[2]` would be `2`, then `j[1]` would be `4`, finally `j[0]` would be `6`. (Or maybe I made a mistake somewhere since I haven't done maths for a long time :-)

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja You can also check my example above to see the problem. Whether I'm right or not, this discussion can help you understand some tricks in dynamic programming :-)

Comment: @XiaoJia Oh, I see what you mean now. You mean that after `j` has passed `k - 1`, a value higher than `j` can be used to computer a current `j` value, which means we have used an element multiple times. That's true, we should use two arrays, I'll fix it up. Thanks.

Comment: @IVlad Correct. And my solution does use two arrays for that purpose :-)

Answer (score 4):

Note: for the special case when the number is `3`, the answer can easily be found in `O(n log n)` time.

Let `S = sum(array)`.
Now, if `S % 3  == 0`, then `S` is the answer.
If `S % 3 == 1`, then to make the sum divisible by `3` you can either remove the smallest element `i` such that `i % 3 == 1`, or remove the smallest `j`, `k` such that `j % 3 == k % 3 == 2`.
If `S % 3 == 2`, then you can either remove the smallest `i` such that `i % 3 == 2`, or the smallest `j`, `k` such that `j % 3 == k % 3 == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MaxSumDivisible 
{

    static int max,divisor;

public static void main(String...okok)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    String ss[]=str.split(" ");
    LinkedList<Integer> list= new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
    {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(ss[i]));
    }
    divisor=sc.nextInt();
    FindMaxSum(list,0);
    System.out.println(max);
}
public static void FindMaxSum(LinkedList<Integer> list, int currentsum)
{
    if(currentsum%divisor==0 && currentsum>max)
    {
        max=currentsum;
    }

    for(int num:list)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> li2= new LinkedList<Integer>(list);
        li2.remove(new Integer(num));
        FindMaxSum(li2,currentsum+num);

    }
}
}
```

It wil work for any numbers.(Only for int).

Comment: This is backtracking and the time complexity is worse than the dynamic programming solution. In my case if I implement this in OA it is giving Time limit Exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is specifically for given number 3. ie. The sum of elements of array divisible by 3. You can generalize this further. 
The main idea is to track for each mod 3, the maximum sum that could be reached.
Time Complexity: O(N).
Space Complexity: O(K) where K is the int by which the sum should be divisible. Here K = 3.

```
class Solution {
    public int maxSumDivThree(int[] nums) {
        int[] dp = new int[3];
        dp[1] = dp[2] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int x : nums) {
            int[] dpNext = new int[3];
            dpNext[0] = Math.max(dp[x%3] + x, dp[0]);
            dpNext[1] = Math.max(dp[(x+1)%3] + x,dp[1]);
            dpNext[2] = Math.max(dp[(x+2)%3] + x,dp[2]);
            dp = dpNext;
        }
        return dp[0];
    }
}
```

LeetCode Weekly Contest 163 [Link to the problem](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-163/problems/greatest-sum-divisible-by-three/).